# Reserving memory for an object in heap without calling its constructor on Arduino

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, heap-memory

I'm working on an arduino project, this is relevant since there's no support for STL nor dynamic allocation on arduino natively. I've noticed that a lot of classes I'm writing do nothing on construction, but have an `.init()` method that actually initializes any resources. This is because that way the class can be initialized in the global scope, and then when the `setup` function runs, actual initialization happens as `.init()` is called there.

For example:

```cpp
const portn_t en=A5, rs=A4, d4=A0, d5=A1, d6=A2, d7=A3;
// making room for that object in the global scope
// this way it can be both used in ``setup()`` and ``loop()``
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);  // Doing the actual initialization
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.write("Hello world!");
  delay(500);
}
```

This works fine for classes that are designed with an `init` or `begin` method. This design pattern is common in most Arduino libraries, but for classes that don't implement this I'm currently using this as a workaround:

```cpp
Button& get_btn_up() {
  // The Button class actually does initialization at construcion
  static Button bt(2, true);
  return bt;
}

Button& get_btn_enter() {
  static Button bt(3, true);
  return bt;
}

Button& get_btn_down() {
  static Button bt(4, true);
  return bt;
}

void setup() {
  // Initializes all the ``Button`` objects
  get_btn_up();
  get_btn_enter();
  get_btn_down();
}

void loop() {
  auto up = get_btn_up();
  if (up.just_pressed()) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Which I don't believe is an optimal solution, as there's a lot of boiler plate just to achieve something that could be done with `new` and some unique pointers.
Because of this I attempted making a `DelayedInit` container class, that would hold the required memory for the object in a union and handle its lifetime

```cpp
template<typename T>
union MemoryOf {
  uint8_t memory [sizeof(T)];
  T obj;
};

template<typename T>
struct DelayedInit {
private:
  MemoryOf<T> memory{.memory={ 0 }};
  bool is_set = false;
public:
  T& get() const {
    memory.obj;
  }
  DelayedInit() {}
  ~DelayedInit() {
    if (is_set)
      get().~T();
  }
  T* operator->() const {
    return &get();
  }
  T& operator*() {
    is_set = true;
    return get();
  }
  const T& operator*() const {
    return get();
  }
  explicit operator bool() const {
    return is_set;
  }
};
```

This implementation is broken at the time, as it locks the arduino up whenever I try to call any methods of the boxed class. Here's how it's supposed to be used

```cpp
DelayedInit<Button> up, enter, down;

void setup() {
  *up = Button(2, true);
  *enter= Button(3, true);
  *down = Button(4, true);
}

void loop() {
  if (up->just_pressed()) {  // Locks up the arduino
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm guessing there's some memory management error in the code that I'm not aware of. What errors are present in the `DelayedInit` implementation? Is there a better approach at solving this issue?

Comment: placement `new()`?

Comment: You forgot the `return` before (what does absolutely nothing on its own) `memory.obj;`, but that's the least of the problems. The template forgets to construct the object, when needed. This is undefined behavior. Assigning something to an unconstructed object is even more undefined behavior. You basically need to reimplement `std::variant` from C++17. That's a lot of code, to do this correctly, much more then what's shown here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for mentioning the return issue! The compiler included in the arduino sdk only supports c++11 without the STL, ``std::vairant`` or ``std::optional`` are not an option.

Comment: @EOF placement new is certainly an option now that I think about it. Would you mind elaborating how to integrate that (or not) into the ``DelayedInit`` class?

Comment: @Facundo You can just call placement new on already allocated memory, then you can use the regular constructor instead of doing ridiculous contortions to avoid writing sane constructors.

Comment: That's why I wrote "to ***reimplement*** `std::variant`". All the work it does is required to correctly implement this kind of functionality with well-formed results.

Comment: it looks like an X->Y problem. use a different library for buttons if this one can't construct global objects

Comment: @Juraj The button thing is an example, I need to use a library that does not do the constructor() then init() dance.

Comment: then use `new` in setup(). as you never `delete` it, then it is not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with. `.init` emulates the pattern that most classes in the arduino libraries use, without actually splitting the init logic in two methods. There's definitely room for improvement, but this works for global variables.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <new>
template<typename T>
union MemoryOf {
  uint8_t memory [sizeof(T)];
  T obj;
  MemoryOf() : memory{ 0 } {};
  ~MemoryOf() {};
};

// Only tested with global variables
// so there might be bugs in the cleanup bits
template<typename T>
struct DelayedInit {
private:
  MemoryOf<T> memory;
  bool is_set = false;
public:
  const T& get() const {
    return memory.obj;
  }
  T& get() {
    return memory.obj;
  }
  void remove() {
    get().~T();
  }
  DelayedInit() {};
  ~DelayedInit() {
    if (is_set)
      remove();
  }
  template<typename ...Args>
  inline void init(Args ...args) {
    if (is_set) {
      remove();
    }
    new (&memory.memory) T(args...); // == &memory.obj
    is_set = true;
  }
  T* operator->() {
    return &get();
  }
  const T* operator->() const {
    return &get();
  }
  T& operator*() {
    return get();
  }
  const T& operator*() const {
    return get();
  }
  explicit operator bool() const {
    return is_set;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
#include "delayed_init.hpp"

DelayedInit<Button> up, enter, down;

void setup() {
  up.init(2, true);
  enter.init(3, true);
  down.init(4, true);
}

void loop() {
  if (up->just_pressed()) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Thanks to [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof) for suggesting the use of placement `new`!